# iOS can't set alpha value of toolbar color since 7.1

Tags: colors, toolbar, alpha, ios7.1, bartintcolor

I have a wired issue after upgrading xcode to include iOS7.1.
The background color of the toolbar appears very bright in simulator and changing the alpha-value doesn't have any effect to it. The red color used to be a light red.

[image]

I set the color in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO]; //animated:YES
[self.navigationController.toolbar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.8f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.5]];
[self.navigationController.toolbar setTranslucent:YES];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Setting an image still works:

```
UIImage* toolbarImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"myimagename"];
[[UIToolbar appearance]
     setBackgroundImage: toolbarImage
     forToolbarPosition: UIToolbarPositionAny
     barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This image can be translucent when it is a png